# Scala async Behavior

Tags: scala, asynchronous

In the following sample method implementation that uses the Scala async:

```
  def doSomething: Future[Int] = async {
    val await1 = await(someFutureResult1()) // Line 1

    val await2 = await(someFutureResult2()) // Line 2

    val syncCall = someFunc3() // Line 3

    await1 + await2 + syncCall // Line 4
  }
```

How is the ordering happening? The caller of doSomething returns immediately because the doSomething() is going to run in an async block. I get that. But what happens when some other thread picks up this execution and executes the contents of doSomething?

My understanding is as follows:

```
Line 1 starts and waits until the Future returned by someFutureResult1() is completed. Line 2 and Line 3 is not yet started!

Line 2 starts and waits until the Future returned by someFutureResult2() is completed

Line 3 starts and returns

Line 4 is called and returned
```

Is the flow correct?

Comment: I'd say it looks correct...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends what you meant by "waits", what happens is that, unlike with Scala's ordinary `Await.result` which blocks the thread, `await` wraps the rest of the code as a `Future`, and frees up the thread to continue running outside the `async` block.

Comment: Does await(...) guarantee me ordering? Is await2 in my example above is run only after the result of await1 is available?

Comment: That's right, in a non-blocking way. That is, it won't hold the executing thread waiting for await1 to complete, and allow the executing thread to continue outside this `async` block (i.e., not the block containing await2).